# HTML/CSS problem: background image is not loading due to Cross-Origin Read Blocking issue

Tags: html, css

For my project, I have to load an image from my image hosting site, I used my github repository for this. my CSS code look like this,

```
#main-section{
    background-image : url("https://github.com/<mypath>/myphoto.jpg");
}
```

Here is my HTML,

```
<section id="main-section">
    <header>
        <h1>Hello Test</h1>
    </header>
</section>
```

However, I am getting CORB issue in my Chrome browser. In the Chrome console the error looks like,

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://github.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

portfolioWebpage.html#about-us:1 A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://github.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://github.com/<mypath>/myphoto.jpg with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Cross-origin problem can be handled by JavaScript and other scripting way, that I know. But I'm feeling rather clueless how to solve this using only HTML and CSS. Could you please suggest anything ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says that the MIME type is `text/html` which means that the server is claiming it is an HTML document.

Since you are requesting the image from Github, this is probably because it **is** an HTML document (possibly one designed to include an `<img>` element to show an image stored in a repository).

You need to use the URL of an actual image.

Comment: Hi Quentin, Thank you for your answer. Thank you very much for pointing out the MIME type issue. Yes, for github "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/" should be the starting path which I was wrongly using earlier. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

there is a mistake in your image URL:
background-image : `url("https://github.com/<mypath>/myphoto.jpg");`

This **`<mypath>`** you are seeing there is a placeholder you need to change that with the actual path you cannot use that. so edit the URL and use the correct URL to the image.